# Variable has null value when using getText but not when rendering a radiobutton

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to render a few radiobuttons in a Struts2 web application.

The `value` of each radiobutton is an integer and its associated label should be an i18n text, which varies as a function of the value. The i18n keys have the form `Common.eventTypeId.<<integer value>>`, (e.g. `Common.eventTypeId.28`, `Common.eventTypeId.29`, etc).

However when I access the page the labels don't get translated as there are wrong keys: `Common.eventTypeId.null`. What puzzles me is that the same variable used to build the i18n key renders ok as the `value` of the radio button.

Here is the snippet where the HTML code is generated. `eventTypeIds` is a `List<Integer>` containing 3 elements: 28, 29 and 31.

```
<s:iterator value="eventTypeIds" var="eTypeId">
    <div class="frm-field">
        <s:set var="label" value="%{getText('Common.eventTypeId.' + eTypeId )}"/>
        <s:radio name="currentActivity.eventTypeId" list="eTypeId" listValue="label"/> 
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

The relevant i18n keys:

```
Common.eventTypeId.29 = CAA
Common.eventTypeId.28 = Practical
Common.eventTypeId.31 = Non-assessable activity
```

This is the actual HTML being generated right now:

```
<div class="frm-field">
    <input type="radio" value="29" checked="checked" id="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId29" name="currentActivity.eventTypeId">
    <label for="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId29">Common.eventTypeId.null</label>
</div>
<div class="frm-field">
    <input type="radio" value="28" id="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId28" name="currentActivity.eventTypeId">
    <label for="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId28">Common.eventTypeId.null</label>
</div>
<div class="frm-field">
    <input type="radio" value="31" id="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId31" name="currentActivity.eventTypeId">
    <label for="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId31">Common.eventTypeId.null</label>
</div>
```

This would be the expected HTML:

```
<div class="frm-field">
    <input type="radio" value="29" checked="checked" id="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId29" name="currentActivity.eventTypeId">
    <label for="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId29">CAA</label>
</div>
<div class="frm-field">
    <input type="radio" value="28" id="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId28" name="currentActivity.eventTypeId">
    <label for="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId28">Practical</label>
</div>
<div class="frm-field">
    <input type="radio" value="31" id="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId31" name="currentActivity.eventTypeId">
    <label for="frm-activity_currentActivity_eventTypeId31">Non-assessable activity</label>
</div>
```

Note that the integer values are being correctly displayed using `eTypeId` variable, but that variable is null when building the i18n key. What am I missing? Did I misunderstand the s:radio tag usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `#` before using `eTypeId` var inside `<s:set>` tag.

```
<s:set var="label" value="%{getText('Common.eventTypeId.' + #eTypeId )}"/>
```

BTW `<s:radio>` takes iterable source in `list` attribute, so you can use your `eventTypeIds` list inside radio tag and get translated text with `listValue` attribute and `top` keyword.

```
<s:radio name="currentActivity.eventTypeId" list="eventTypeIds" 
              listValue="%{getText('Common.eventTypeId.' + top)}"/>
```